# How to find dim(S∩T)

Tags: linear-algebra

I have S and T in the subspace of $R^4$ and defined by

$S={[s, t, 0, 0]|s, t ∈ R}$

$T={[0, s, t, 0]|s, t ∈ R}$

Then I am asked to find $dim(S)$, $dim(T)$, and $dim(S∩T)$.  From what I have gathered, the dimensions of the first two are 4 each, but I'm lost on how to find the dimension of an intersection.

Thanks!

Comment: a) Check your ideas for $\dim S$, and $\dim T$ (Hint: How many subspaces of dimension $4$ are ther in $\mathbb R^4$?) b) Start by describing $S\cap T$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Roughly, the dimension is the number of degrees of freedom. So for both $S,T$, how many parameters can be varied independently?

$x \in S$ **iff** $x \in \operatorname{sp} \{ e_1, e_2 \}$, 
$x \in T$ **iff** $x \in \operatorname{sp} \{ e_2, e_3 \}$, and the vectors $e_k$ are linearly independent.

From this you should be able to read off $\dim S, \dim T$.

Now note that $x \in S \cap T$ **iff** $x \in S$ and $x \in T$ **iff** $x \in \operatorname{sp} \{e_2 \}$. Now you should be able to read off the dimension of $T \cap S$.

Comment: So it must be that $x∈S$ and $x∈T$, and since we only have $e2$ as the common vector of both, that must mean s and t are $∈S∩T$, meaning the dimension is 2, right?

Comment: Well, a little care is needed here. If $x \in S$, it can be written as $x = s_1 e_1 + s_2 e_2$, and if $x \in T$, it can be written as $x = t_2 e_2 + t_3 e_3 $. Then since $x=x$, we have $s_1 e_1 + s_2 e_2 = t_2 e_2 + t_3 e_3 $, and since the $e_k$ are linearly independent, this gives $s_1 = 0$, $s_2=t_2$ and $t_3 = 0$. So, in fact $x = s_2 e_2$. That is, every $x$ in the intersection can be written as a multiple of $e_2$. So it has dimension **one**.

Comment: Well, I was off.  Unfortunately, there was no explanation how to find this in the lesson.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3):

We have
$$S=\mathrm{span}\left(e_1=(1,0,0,0),e_2=(0,1,0,0)\right)$$
so $\dim S=2$ and
$$T=\mathrm{span}\left(e_2=(0,1,0,0),e_3=(0,0,1,0)\right)$$
so $\dim T=2$ and $\dim S\cap T\in \{0,1,2\}$.  Notice that $e_2\in S\cap T$ and $e_1\not\in S\cap T$. Can you deduce $\dim S\cap T$?

Comment: Good points Sami. :-)